# systemctl through python

Tags: python, systemctl

Is there is any way I can use `systemctl status` API through python?
I'm looking for another method that running this command in sub process as than I need to parse output (that might cause issue if output change in future).

Comment: Use dbus: https://trstringer.com/python-systemd-dbus/

Comment: thankyou so much @muru

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [systemd’s D-Bus API](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html):

```python
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
systemd = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.systemd1', '/org/freedesktop/systemd1')
manager = dbus.Interface(systemd, 'org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager')
```

Then `manager.ListUnits()` will return all the configured units, with their load state, active state and sub states. There are variants of this method with filters.